# how to place video record from testcontainers to allure-report

Tags: java, allure, testcontainers

This approach don't work, I tried converting FILE to InputStream and vise versa. maybe someone found yourself with the same trouble

```
static File file = new File("videos");

@Container
public static final BrowserWebDriverContainer browser =
        new BrowserWebDriverContainer()
                .withCapabilities(DesiredCapabilities.firefox())
                .withRecordingMode(
                        BrowserWebDriverContainer.VncRecordingMode.RECORD_ALL,
                        file,
                        VncRecordingContainer.VncRecordingFormat.MP4);

 @Test
 void tempTest() {
    @(".someId").click;
 }    


@AfterAll
    static void clean_up() throws FileNotFoundException {
        InputStream vid = new FileInputStream(file.toString());
        Allure.addAttachment("video", "video/mp4", vid, "mp4");

        WebDriverRunner.closeWebDriver();
    }
```

Core problem how to place

```
.withRecordingMode(                        
        BrowserWebDriverContainer.VncRecordingMode.RECORD_ALL,
        "THIS VIDEO DIRECTORY TO",
        VncRecordingContainer.VncRecordingFormat.MP4);

Allure.addAttachment("video", "video/mp4", HERE, "mp4");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```java
   public void allureVid() {
       try {
           byte[] byteArr = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream("src/test/resources/videoplayback.mp4"));
           Allure.addAttachment("attachment name", "video/mp4", new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArr), "mp4");
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
```

[image]